# is it possible to get formatted date object in Java

Tags: java, spring, jsf, date

```
     SimpleDateFormat formatter= 
      new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd");
     String dateNow = formatter.format(rs.getDate("ExpirationDate").getTime());
System.out.println("Date in String: "+dateNow);
     expDate = formatter.parse(dateNow);
System.out.println("expDate: "+expDate);
```

Here is the code through which I am trying to format the date to `2013 Apr 26` format.Now `SimpleDateFormat#format` method returns a formatted String but I need a `java.util.Date` object with desired format? Is it possible
**Note:** Actually I need the date object becuase I have to print it on my JSF page and when I tried to print it on JSF it shows defualt format of `java.util.Date` i-e `Mon Mar 04 00:00:00 PKT 2013` whereas I want this `2013 Apr 26`
Another thing is that I found a annotation is Spring framework which is `@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy MMM dd")` which works itself.Is there anything like this annotation in JSF 2.0.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Date` class does not store any information about formatting. The `Date` class exist basically merely of a `private long milliseconds` field. The format which you're seeing when you're printing a `Date` instance is just its default `toString()` format which is clearly specified in [its javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29).

In JSF context, you need [`<f:convertDateTime>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/convertDateTime.html) tag to convert between `Date` in model and `String` in HTML/HTTP. This can be used in both `UIOutput` and `UIInput` components.

```html
<h:outputText value="#{bean.date}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy MMM dd" />
</h:outputText>
...
<h:inputText value="#{bean.date}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
</h:inputText>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a formatted Date object. Date objects have no intrinsic format other than the one used in their toString method. You need to use a dateformat to format them in a specific way, just like you do in your question.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
public class MyDate extends Date{

    public String toString(){
        SimpleDateFormat formatter= 
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd");
        String dateNow = formatter.format(this.getTime());
        String ans="";
        ans+="Date in String: "+dateNow;
        expDate = formatter.parse(dateNow);
        ans+="\n"+"expDate: "+expDate;
        return ans;
    }    
}
```

with this you can use MyDate and it will be printed as you want.

```
System.out.println(new MyDate());
```