# How to display java.util.Date in 2013-07-15 22:00:45 format

Tags: jsf, date

I have a variable stored in TIMESTAMP format in db. It stores time like this:

```
2013-07-15 22:00:45
```

I want to take this and use it in a h:outputText item. I make a database search, and store the results in a resultset.

```
java.util.Date dt= res.getTimestamp(5);
```

Then i want to use this date, which was read from database, in an outputtext item. But doing the following does not work:

```
<h:outputText value="#{list.date}"
```

Where `list` is an `ArrayList`. I am sure that list.date is the date I read from database but I cannot get its value with the format I specified. So how can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to get formatted date object in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184786/is-it-possible-to-get-formatted-date-object-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [change the date format in jsf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390663/change-the-date-format-in-jsf)

Comment: maybe duplicate, but my problem is, <h:outputText value="#{list.date}" displays nothing, not that it displays date in a different format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<h:outputText value="#{list.date}">
    <f:convertDateTime type="both" pattern="YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"/>
</h:outputText>
```

Comment: You were faster than me ! :-)

Comment: There's another interesting option called [Prettytime](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) which works really well for formatting timestamps. Have a look if you want.

Comment: i tried this but i get the following error: <f:convertDateTime> Parent not an instance of ValueHolder: org.richfaces.component.UIColumn@2a444f40

Comment: @iceface Please, make sure `list.date` is of type `Date` and `list.getDate()` isn't coming *null*.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal shpuld list.date be java.sql.date or java.util.date?

Comment: @iceface `java.util.Date`

Comment: @RaviThapliyal well thanks i solved the problem that helped a lot

Comment: @iceface Glad to help. By the way, you may use `utilDate = new java.util.Date(sqlDate.getTime());` to convert between the two easily.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can use JSF's convertDateTime tag.

e.g. :

```html
<h:outputText value="#{list.date}">
    <f:convertDateTime pattern="d-M-yyyy" />
</h:outputText>
```

See http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_convertDateTime.html